# How to deallocate memory assigned to triple pointer?

Tags: c

Hi i want to free allocated memory which is allocated like below using malloc :

````
```
int ret = 0;
    int nrow = 0, ncol = 0, i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    char *err_messg;
    char **result;
    char ***recordset;
    ResultSet resultSet_Table;
    char RET[10];

    char sql_string[QUERY_BUFF_SIZE]; //this honestly needs to be more elegant; will do for now
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    sql_string[0] = '\0';
    printf("Temp called 3\n");
    ret = vsprintf(sql_string, fmt, args);
    printf("Temp called 4\n");
    va_end(args);
    printf("\n%s\n", sql_string);

    //initialize resultSet_Table;
    resultSet_Table.rows = 0;
    resultSet_Table.cols = 0;
    resultSet_Table.recordset = NULL;

    //        if(sqlite3_open("/home/ap/pub/CONFIG.DB", &StructSql) == SQLITE_OK)
    //        {

    printf("Database Opened\n");
    // CTOS_LCDTPrintXY(1, 1, "DB Opened");


    ret = sqlite3_get_table(
            StructSql,
            sql_string,
            &result,
            &nrow,
            &ncol,
            &err_messg
            );
    printf("nrow=%d ncol=%d\n", nrow, ncol);

char*** recordset = (char ***) malloc(nrow * sizeof (char **));
 
for (count = ncol; count < ((nrow + 1) * ncol); count++) {
        
    printf("Enter in LOOP\n");
    recordset[i] = (char **) malloc(ncol * sizeof (char *));
    for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++) 
    {
        printf("%s ", result[count]);
        recordset[i][j] = (char *) malloc((strlen(result[count]) + 1));
        strcpy(recordset[i][j], result[count]);
        
        if (j != (ncol - 1))
            count++;
    }
    i++;
    printf("\n");
}
```
````

I want to free this memory but how to do it using free(). i have tried to free it like below:

```
int i = 0;
    
for (count = ncol; count < ((nrow + 1) * ncol); count++) {
    
    printf("Enter in LOOP\n");
      
    for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
        free(recordset[i][j]);
        
        if (j != (ncol - 1))
            count++;
    }
    free(recordset[i]); 
    i++;
    printf("\n");
}
    
free(recordset);
```

When i wrote this code My program start to crash. Can anybody help me to what i wrote wrong in this code?

Actually memory allocated for sqlite3_get_table()  result. the memory allocation is done successfully but when i try to free it. it create the problem.

Comment: can you paste the full code ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Are there any error messages? Technically, you should be able to free the memory exactly the same way you used to allocate it.

Comment: Why are you multiplying `nrow` by `ncol`. You would only need to do this if you were allocating the 2D array as a flat row-major array. If you're allocating the rows and columns separately, you don't need to multiply.

Comment: As far as freeing goes, you should use the same loops to free as you do to allocate, just in reverse. It looks like you're doing that, so the freeing is correct.

Comment: `for (count = ncol; count < ((nrow + 1) * ncol); count++)` seems very suspicious. Why do you start at `ncol` instead of `0`?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Yes so i have tried it. But actually i not know  the code i wrote for deallocate is right or wrong ? and if it is wrong then what is wrong ? i want to know with code example.

Comment: @Barmar i have used the above code to store result of sqlite3_get_table(). where A result table is an array of pointers to zero-terminated UTF-8 strings. There are (N+1)*M elements in the array. The first M pointers point to zero-terminated strings that contain the names of the columns. The remaining entries all point to query results. So i have allocated memory like above.

Comment: For  each call to `malloc()`, there must be a matching call `free()`.  You need to free the memory more or less in the reverse of the order it was allocated (so `free(recordset)` should indeed be last).  Have you got [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) available?  If so, use it.

Comment: Your for loop increments `count` but you index the records with `i` which is incremented at the bottom of each loop. It makes your code hard to understand at best. For example, if ncol = 10 and nrow = 100, your loop will increment `i` way more times than I think you're expecting it to.

Comment: why i started count from ncol.  for that you can refer this link https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html

Comment: Why are you using a legacy interface (`sqlite3_get_table()`) where it says "Use of this interface is not recommended."  That strongly hints you should not use it in new code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes but throughout the project this function used. and i not allowed to change it.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, for each call to `malloc()`, there must be a matching call `free()`.  You need to free the memory more or less in the reverse of the order it was allocated (so `free(recordset)` should indeed be last).

Your memory allocation code is broken.  Your memory freeing code is similarly broken.

According to a comment, you have `nrows + 1` rows of data, each containing `ncols` values, each of which is a null-terminated string.  It isn't clear that you have to copy the information from `results`, but it does ensure that the memory is wholly under your control.

You've not shown most of your variable declarations — that always makes life unnecessarily hard for those who would help you.

The code below omits checks for memory allocation failures.  You should not omit those — but freeing up space already allocated when an allocation fails becomes fiddly.

You should have a function along the lines of:

```c
char ***array_to_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char *results[])
{
    char ***recordset = malloc((nrows + 1) * sizeof(*recordset));
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        recordset[i] = malloc(ncols * sizeof(recordset[0][0]));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            //recordset[i][j] = strdup(results[count++];
            recordset[i][j] = malloc(strlen(results[count]) + 1);
            strcpy(recordset[i][j], results[count++]);
        }
    }
    return recordset;
}
```

Then your release code becomes:

```c
void free_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
     {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
              free(recordset[i][j]);
         free(recordset[i]);
     }
     free(recordset);
}
```

<sup>*No compiler was consulted about the validity of this code before the initial posting.  There could be bugs in it (apart from the absence of checking memory allocations) — indeed, there were two typo bugs that stopped it compiling (`counter` vs `count`, and a missing close parenthesis).*</sup>

#### Code in test harness

```c
/* SO 7140-4900 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char ***array_to_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char *results[])
{
    char ***recordset = malloc((nrows + 1) * sizeof(*recordset));
    size_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        recordset[i] = malloc(ncols * sizeof(recordset[0][0]));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            //recordset[i][j] = strdup(results[count++];
            recordset[i][j] = malloc(strlen(results[count]) + 1);
            strcpy(recordset[i][j], results[count++]);
        }
    }
    return recordset;
}

static void free_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
     {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
              free(recordset[i][j]);
         free(recordset[i]);
     }
     free(recordset);
}

// Test Harness

static size_t max_string_width(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
    size_t maxwid = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            size_t length = strlen(recordset[i][j]);
            if (length > maxwid)
                maxwid = length;
        }
    }
    return maxwid;
}

static void dump_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
    int maxwid = max_string_width(nrows, ncols, recordset);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%-*s", pad, maxwid, recordset[i][j]);
            pad = "  ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *results[] =
    {
        "Name",  "Number",
        /* random -n 4 -T '%W%v%c%v%c %[10:99]d' | commalist -S -q '"' -B 8 */
        "Caqam", "18",
        "Cepay", "38",
        "Jojaj", "43",
        "Tovun", "59",
    };
    enum { NUM_ROWS = 4, NUM_COLS = 2 };

    char ***recordset = array_to_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, results);
    dump_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, recordset);
    free_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, recordset);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Name    Number
Caqam   18    
Cepay   38    
Jojaj   43    
Tovun   59
```

There are no leaks reported by the `leaks` program on macOS, and no memory abuse reported when the macOS `malloc()` code is configured to test for memory abuses.

#### Testing for and recovering from allocation failure

This variant of the code includes a function `xmalloc()` which can be configured to start failing after a given number of allocations.  The code then tests the failure paths after 1..30 allocations (there are only 16 allocations anyway).  It too is leak-free and memory abuse-free.

```c
/* SO 7140-4900 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Generate allocation failures */
static size_t counter = 0;
static size_t failure = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (failure > 0 && ++counter >= failure)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s() failed (counter = %zu, failure = %zu)\n", __func__, counter, failure);
        return NULL;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

static char ***array_to_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char *results[])
{
    char ***recordset = xmalloc((nrows + 1) * sizeof(*recordset));
    if (recordset == NULL)
        return NULL;

    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        recordset[i] = xmalloc(ncols * sizeof(recordset[0][0]));
        if (recordset[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (size_t ei = 0; ei < i; ei++)
            {
                for (size_t ej = 0; ej < ncols; ej++)
                    free(recordset[ei][ej]);
                free(recordset[ei]);
            }
            free(recordset);
            return NULL;
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            //recordset[i][j] = strdup(results[count++];
            recordset[i][j] = xmalloc(strlen(results[count]) + 1);
            if (recordset[i][j] == NULL)
            {
                for (size_t ej = 0; ej < j; ej++)
                    free(recordset[i][ej]);
                free(recordset[i]);
                for (size_t ei = 0; ei < i; ei++)
                {
                    for (size_t ej = 0; ej < ncols; ej++)
                        free(recordset[ei][ej]);
                    free(recordset[ei]);
                }
                free(recordset);
                return NULL;
            }
            strcpy(recordset[i][j], results[count++]);
        }
    }
    return recordset;
}

static void free_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
     for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
     {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
              free(recordset[i][j]);
         free(recordset[i]);
     }
     free(recordset);
}

static size_t max_string_width(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
    size_t maxwid = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            size_t length = strlen(recordset[i][j]);
            if (length > maxwid)
                maxwid = length;
        }
    }
    return maxwid;
}

static void dump_recordset(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, char ***recordset)
{
    int maxwid = max_string_width(nrows, ncols, recordset);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows + 1; i++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            printf("%s%-*s", pad, maxwid, recordset[i][j]);
            pad = "  ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *results[] =
    {
        "Name",  "Number",
        /* random -n 4 -T '%W%v%c%v%c %[10:99]d' | commalist -S -q '"' -B 8 */
        "Caqam", "18",
        "Cepay", "38",
        "Jojaj", "43",
        "Tovun", "59",
    };
    enum { NUM_ROWS = 4, NUM_COLS = 2 };

    for (failure = 0; failure < 30; failure++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        char ***recordset = array_to_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, results);
        if (recordset != NULL)
        {
            dump_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, recordset);
            free_recordset(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS, recordset);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code releasing memory after an allocation failure has to deal with with partially allocated rows, previous fully allocated rows, and of course the initial allocation.

**Output**

```
Name    Number
Caqam   18    
Cepay   38    
Jojaj   43    
Tovun   59    
xmalloc() failed (counter = 1, failure = 1)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 2, failure = 2)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 3, failure = 3)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 4, failure = 4)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 5, failure = 5)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 6, failure = 6)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 7, failure = 7)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 8, failure = 8)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 9, failure = 9)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 10, failure = 10)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 11, failure = 11)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 12, failure = 12)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 13, failure = 13)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 14, failure = 14)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 15, failure = 15)
xmalloc() failed (counter = 16, failure = 16)
Name    Number
Caqam   18    
Cepay   38    
Jojaj   43    
Tovun   59    
…
```

The output reappears when the allocation failure doesn't occur because not enough memory allocations occur.

Comment: Oh, I love the disclaimer at the bottom of your answer! :-D